# The analyticity of $f(z)=\frac{e^{i\theta(z)}}{1+|z|^2}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\theta(z)$ be a real-valued function of a complex variable such that

(1)say $z=x+iy$, regarded as a real function of two variables, $\theta(z)=\theta(x,y)$ is smooth at $(x,y)=(0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$;

(2)$\theta(z)$ is not differentiable at each point in a neighborhood of $z=0$.

As we know $1+|z|^2$ is not differentiable on $\mathbb{C}$ but at $z=0$. The question is, can $$f(z)=\frac{e^{i\theta(z)}}{1+|z|^2}$$ be analytic at $z=0$?

Comment: No, because $|f(z)| =|f(|z|)|$, and the only such analytic function is $f(z) =C z^k$, but $|C z^k | \ne \frac{1}{1+|z|^2}$

Comment: Also, by the maixmum principle, $f(z)$ being analytic at $z=0$ leads to a contradiction.